# Persistent constants between rails console sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

To reproduce this you need two files in a brandnew rails dir:

```
# config/initializers/test.rb
load Rails.root.join 'lib', 'test.rb'
```

and

```
# lib/test.rb
module Test
  # BLA ||= "Oh nooooooooooooooo!"
  BLA ||= "Oh Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees!"
end
```

Then start a rails console session with `rails c` and type `Test::BLA`

```
irb(main):001:0> Test::BLA
=> "Oh Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees!"
```

Edit the Test module like this:

```
# lib/test.rb
module Test
  BLA ||= "Oh nooooooooooooooo!"
  # BLA ||= "Oh Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees!"
end
```

Restart the console:

```
irb(main):001:0> Test::BLA
=> "Oh Yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees!"
```

This is absolutely annoying.

The only way to get rid of the old state and to really cleanly restart the rails console is to close **all** shell sessions in which `rails c` has been run. - Yes, it is contagious.

Where/how TF is that state stored?

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of a major change in Rails 4, for performance issues a Rails instance is kept open so you can load the environment very quickly after the first load.

Constants, however, should be constant, defined once in any instance of an application. You should solve this problem by defining your constant with an equals, instead of an or equals (unlike other attributes, it should always have the value which is in the file.)

```
# lib/test.rb
module Test
  BLA = "Oh crumbs!"
end
```

If this is a value which you want to set and re-set, try a module attribute

```
# lib/test.rb
module Test
  mattr_accessor :bla
end
```

You can then set it with a double @ just like class variables.

Or, if you are including your module in a class, use `cattr_accessor` instead, to make it a variable in that class.

Answer (score 0):

There are running some `spring` processes in the background. A radical solution with possibly ugly side effects is:

```
killall ruby && rails c
```

But surely better is to comment out the `gem 'spring'` line in the `Gemfile`.